# Глобальное условие в алгоритме

Tags: алгоритм, условия, блок-схема

Необходимо создать визуальный алгоритм программы (Блок-схема), но так, как выход осуществляется по нажатию кнопки выход пользователем или при ошибке (Почти в любой точке алгоритма), не могу это изобразить, есть ли какие-либо способы изобразить это, а если нет, то где обозначить данное правило.
Естественно переходить к этому после каждого действия - не вариант.

Comment: с помощью блок-схемы вряд ли, но возможно помогут [UML диаграммы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine)

Comment: К сожалению у меня задача создать именно алгоритм в виде блок-схемы

Comment: Поздравляют, тебе задали невозможную задачу :)

Comment: Вам нужно просто найти или придумать блок-схему для элемента "событие".

Comment: @vp_arth. а есть такой элемент? :)

Comment: В ГОСТ может и нету. А по духу - это можно просто отобразить, как начало подпрограммы с описанием, при каком событии оно вызывается.

Comment: Ну и можно завести таки liveloop и время от времени спрашивать "Не произошло ли событие?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да. Теперь я понял. Вам нужна блок-схема. Тогда в самом начале блок схемы можно вставить два оператора While do. В первом условие "Пока нет ошибок" во втором "Пока не нажата кнопка Выход" выполняется тело программы иначе конец программ.

Помимо варианта с двумя условными операторами while перед началом основного тела программы, есть вариант с параллельным процессом. ГОСТ 19.701-90. символ 3.2.2.5. Параллельные действия. Т.е. Изначально программы делится на три параллельных процесса: первый - ожидание ошибки иначе выход, второй - ожидание нажатия кнопки иначе выход, третий - тело вышей программы.

Хотя параллельный процесс это всё-таки  новый поток, но возможно этот вариант будет логично отображать то, что вы хотите.

Comment: Пожалуйста не создавайте 2 ответа на 1 вопрос, воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править" для основного ответа, а второй удалите.

Comment: мне лично больше нравится идея с параллельным процессом. Все-таки пользователь - внешний фактор. Вносить его в алгоритм работы программы циклом не очень красивое решение. То ли дело, показать, что он может воздействовать на главный поток.

Comment: В виде цикла алгоритм будет неверным, т.к. это будет предполагать возможность завершения только после исполнения всего тела и перехода к условию. Сделал, как вы и говорите, три параллельных процесса: Нажата кнопка "Выход"->Обработка нажатия || Обработка основных процессов || Исключение->Обработка исключения. Исключения конечно не идут в отдельном потоке, но вот обработка нажатий - наоборот идет именно в отдельном потоке, т.к. это JavaFX.